# dimension of a subspace given by the direct sum of some subspaces in $R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a doubt about the dimension of a subspace given by the direct sum of some subspaces in $R^4$.
I have two subspaces in $R^4$, $U_k$ and $W_k$.
I know that 
$$dim(U_k) = \begin{cases}1 &  if  k\ne0, -1\\
2   &  if k=0, -1\end{cases}$$

$$dim(W_k) = \begin{cases}2 &  if k=-1 \\
3   &  if k\ne-1\end{cases}$$

I have to determine if it is possible the existence of a subspace $Z\subseteq R^4$ such that $$U_k \oplus Z=W_k \oplus Z$$

My attempt is:
it is necessary that $dim U_k+dim Z=dim W_k+dim Z \Rightarrow dim U_k=dim W_k$
 and this condition is true when $k=-1$.

In this case we can say that Z can exist and $dim Z=2 or 1$ because we are in $R^4$.

In the suggested solution it is said that $dim U_k=dim W_k=2=dim Z$
but I can't see why $dim Z$ has to be 2 since that $U_k \oplus Z$ or$W_k \oplus Z$ could alse be different from $R^4$.

Comment: As you say this can only occur if $\dim U_k=\dim W_k$. As for the dimension of $Z$ you can always achieve $2$ but whether you can achieve less depends on what exactly $U_k$ and $W_k$ are.

Comment: @lord Sharp the unknown so is the Sum  4 in anycase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly obtained $k=-1$ and $\dim U_{-1} = \dim V_{-1} = 2$. There are now $3$ possible cases:

- $U_{-1} = W_{-1}$:

  - choose an algebraic complement of $U_{-1}$ (it will have dimension $2$)
  - either choose $Z$ a $1$-dimensional subspace of it, or choose $Z$ to be the whole complement
  - notice that in this case you may freely choose the dimension of $Z$;
- $U_{-1} \cap W_{-1} = \text{span } \{v\} \ne \{0\}$:

  - choose $u \in U_{-1}$ and $w \in W_{-1}$ such that $\{v,u\}$ and $\{v,w\}$ be bases in $U_{-1}$ and $W_{-1}$
  - notice that $\{v,u,w\}$ is linearly independent, therefore there exists $t \in \Bbb R^4$ that completes it to a basis of $\Bbb R^4$
  - take $Z = \text{span } \{t\}$ - it will have dimension $1$
  - notice that there is no $Z$ with $\dim Z = 2$: if such a $Z$ existed, then $Z = \text{span } \{s,t\}$ and it would follow that $\{v,u,w,s,t\}$ would be linearly independent - impossible in $\Bbb R^4$;
- $U_{-1} \cap W_{-1} = \{0\}$:

  - let $\{u, u'\}$ and $\{w, w'\}$ be bases in $U_{-1}$ and $V_{-1}$
  - if $0 \ne z \in Z$ then $\{u, u', w, w', z\}$ would be linearly independent in $\Bbb R^4$, which would be impossible
  - it follows that in this last case $Z = \{0\}$.

Comment: My question is :is the sentence $dim U_k=W_z=dim Z $ a particular case or not? In other words should it be$dim (U_k \oplus Z)=dim(W_k \oplus Z)=4$ or is this a particular case?

Comment: @Anne: A particular case of what? Here, think about this: consider the subspaces $U = \text{span } \{e_1, e_2\}$ and $W = \text{span } \{e_3, e_4\}$. Try to find a non-zero vector linearly independent from both $U$ and $W$ - if you succeed, i'll pay you your weight in gold!

Comment: I mean that it is not necessary that the sum $dim U_k+dim Z=4$ or $dim W_k+dim Z=4$, so the sum can also be 3.

Comment: @Anne: Yes, that sum can also be $3$ - it always happens if $\dim U \cap W = 1$ and it may happen if $U = W$, as shown in my analysis above.

Comment: Thanks for your complete analysis!!